# SLDS in Visual Force - How to render a conditional div?

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, slds

I have a slds-grid that I want to display conditionaaly
I tried `<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters" rendered="{on condition true}">`

doesn't work, condition is correct. Tried using 'aura:if' but seems like I need to import some lib for it to work, only adding  at start of the page is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apex:outputText:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!someCondition}">
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
    ...
  </div>
</apex:outputText>
```

---

Or, you can add in slds-hide:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters {!if(someCondition,'','slds-hide')}">
```